# Infinite recursive list from function

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have two infinite lists `c` and `h`.

I also have a function

`f :: OLG -> Int -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double`,

where `OLG` is a data type I defined.

I would like to construct a third infinite list that has the following form

```
a :: [Double]
a = [     0.0, 
     f m 0 ↑ (c!!0) (h!!0) w_ave,
     f m 1 ↑ (c!!1) (h!!1) w_ave,
     f m 2 ↑ (c!!2) (h!!2) w_ave,
     f m 3 ↑ (c!!3) (h!!3) w_ave,
     f m 4 ↑ (c!!4) (h!!4) w_ave,
     f m 5 ↑ (c!!5) (h!!5) w_ave,
     f m 6 ↑ (c!!6) (h!!6) w_ave,
     ⋮,
     f m i ↑ (c!!i) (h!!i) w_ave,
     ]
```

where  `m :: OLG`, `c :: [Double]`, `h :: [Double]` and `w_ave :: Double`. The uparrow (`↑`) represents a placeholder that says the third argument of `f` should be the previous element of the list we are constructing.

I imagine there is a clean/recursive way to do this, but being new to Hasekll I can't think of it. Perhaps I need to use `iterate` somehow?

This problem reminds me a bit of the standard implementation of the infinite list of fibonacci numbers

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

in that successive elements of the list are computed by applying a function to previous list elements.

Comment: Here's a hint: start with the form `a = 0.0 : zipWith4 g ? ? ? ?` where `g` is a function and the four `?`s are four lists. Then work out what `g` and the four `?`s should be (one of the `?`s will refer back to `a`).

Comment: @ReidBarton, excellent hint. I was able to solve it! Should I post a separate answer, or just edit my original post?

Comment: @spencerlyon2 Separate answer. You can also accept it after a while.

Comment: @ReidBarton Oh, I see. It's `a = 0.0 : zipWith4 g [0..] a c h`. Clever. And if you put `w_ave` at the beginning you can even express `g` as `f m w_ave`.

Comment: @Jefffrey, good point about moving `w_ave` to the front and then Haskell's partial application do the job for me. I'll implement that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the hint from @ReidBarton I was able to solve this. Here is what I came up with:

NOTE: as pointed out by @Jeffrey, to simplify the code and allow partial application to define the g function for us, I have re-defined `f` so that the `i`th element of `a` will be `f m w_ave i ↑ (c!!i) (h!!i)` (I moved `w_ave` to be the second argument instead of the last one).

This means the type of f is now `f :: OLG -> Double -> Int -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double`

```
alist :: OLG -> [Double] -> [Double] -> [Double]
alist m cs hs = as
    where as = 0.0 : zipWith4 (f m w_ave) [0..] as cs hs
```

Comment: You can express `g` in terms of `f` if you move `w_ave` after `m`: `g = f m w_ave`.

Comment: You should also probably be using `[0..]` instead of `[1..]`.

Comment: @Jefffrey I had that originally, but I'm actually working off some Python code I have that I believe to be correct. When I use `[1..]` I get the same answer as python, but `[0..]` results in a different answer. Perhaps this is showing a bug in the original python...

Comment: Found the bug... it was actually in the `f` function. Our initial thought of `[0..]` is correct. Thanks for commenting.